# Wix installer (3.0) - how do I write to the Registry after success or fail of the installation?

Tags: wix, wix3

I have an application that will be installed by another program (basically a wrapper that installs multiple applications and reports pass/fail for each). The requirement from the wrapper development team is that my application must write either *Success* or *Fail* to a specific registry key after the installation completes.

For my solution, I was thinking I could initilize the registry key to *Success* when the installtion begins, and update the value to *Fail* only if the installation fails (or the other way around).

Based on reading examples, browsing through the Wix Help, and searching for similar issues, I'm pretty certain I need to use a Custom Action, something like

```
<Custom Action="SetInstallationStatusFail" After="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
```

The place I'm stuck at now is that I don't know what code I need to write for the *SetInstallationStatusFail* in order to update the registry key. I'm also not sure what Parent element to stck it under. I think it should be something simple like this

```
<RegistryValue Action="write" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\$(var.RegistryCompanyName)\$(var.RegistryProductName)\InstallStatus" Name="install" Type="string" Value="Fail" />
```

If you think I'm trying to do something that isn't valid, or if you know of a better solution for wrting to the registry after install, please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option would be to test if the value in the registry exists.

Your installer writes a value to the registry, the value can be *Success*. If the value exists in the registry, then installation was successful; if it does not, then installation failed.

Comment: I asked the dev team what happens if the registry key doesn't exist after install...their app assumes my installation failed. So, for the short term, I'll write success during install, and on a failure, there will be no key. For the long term, I think I'll try to get them to accept the standard return codes. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bad requirement because the registry value would be "orphaned" with nothing to clean it up. MSI already provides a way to determine success or failure: the return code. See "Error Codes" in the MSI SDK for a list.

MSI doesn't provide a way to write to the HKLM registry after failure, either natively or via custom action. (There are actions that can be triggered on error but they don't have privileges to write to HKLM.)

Comment: Thanks Bob. I agree the requirement is bad, and I'm trying to get the team to accept standard return codes to work, but I'm not sure how willing they are to change at this point. What about writing to something other than HKLM? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Have a chat to the wrapper guys and see if they are willing to consider other options - even if they can't accept return codes and want to check somewhere else there are still other ways to do this using the Windows Installer API.

For example, here's a really simple VBScript to loop through the currently installed products looking to see if an application is installed by name.

```
productName = "My Application"

Set installer = Wscript.CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")

For Each productCode In installer.Products
    If LCase(installer.ProductInfo(productCode, "ProductName")) = LCase(productName) Then Exit For
Next

If IsEmpty(productCode) Then 
    Wscript.Echo "Couldn't find " & productName
Else
    Wscript.Echo "Found " & productName
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a thought. You can write registry value in both cases in the success case or failure case. Write a custom action to write success value. Write and schedule a rollback custom action to write failed value. If install fails it will be rolled back and the rollback custom action will write failed. If it succeeds you write value success in the custom action with condition not installed.

In either case These registry values can be deleted during uninstall. This may not be an elegant solution but if this is your requirement then you can fulfill it.

Perhaps Bob Arnson can comment upon this solution.